# Codeigniter and AngularJS bug: pagination does not work when the application is not in the root directory

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I am working on a **blog application** with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **AngularJS v1.7.8**.

The Dashboard of the application is "pure" Codeigniter, with Models, Controllers, and views, while the fronted is made up of JSONs managed and displayed by AngularJS. (I operated this clear *separation* between back-end and front-end in order to enable "themeing".)

The posts are paginated. On the back-end, in the *Posts controller*, the posts list looks like this:

```
private function _initPagination($path, $totalRows, $query_string_segment = 'page') {
  //load and configure pagination 
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $path;
    $config['query_string_segment'] = $query_string_segment; 
    $config['enable_query_strings'] =TRUE;
    $config['reuse_query_string'] =TRUE;
    $config['total_rows'] = $totalRows;
    $config['per_page'] = 12;
    if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
        $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
    }
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $limit = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;

    return ['limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset];
}

public function index() {

  //call initialization method
    $config = $this->_initPagination("/", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());

    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();  

  //use limit and offset returned by _initPaginator method
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);

    // All posts
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

On the front-end, in AngularJS, I have:

```
 // All posts
.controller('PostsController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    //Get current page (?page=2, ?page=3 etc)
    const currPage = window.location.search;

    // Get all the posts on the current page 
    $http.get('api/' + currPage).then(function(response) {

        //Categories
        $scope.categories = response.data.categories;

        // Posts
        $scope.posts = response.data.posts;

        // posts pagination
        $scope.pagination = response.data.pagination;

    });
}])
```

The problem is that the pagination does not work (the links are pointing to the wrong likne) when the application is **not** in the root directory (it is at www.examplesite.com/blog, not at www.examplesite.com).

I suppose it has something to do Codeigniter's `base_url()` but I have not been able to spot the bug and fix it.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "does not work" means in your case?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes, have a look **[here](http://code-love.tk/apiblog/)**.

Comment: So, if page 2 would point to http://code-love.tk/apiblog/?page=2 instead of http://code-love.tk/?page=2 (and so on), then it would be working according to your expectations?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $path;
```

Because `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is always the root without other directory.

You need to use something like:

```
$config['base_url'] = str_replace("/api/", "/", base_url()) . $path;
```

But I recomand you to implement the pagination in your front end (Angular) and in CI you need only something like:

```
public function index($offset, $limit) {
    $data = [];
    $data['count'] = $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();  
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($limit, $offset);

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this line:

```
$config = $this->_initPagination("/", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());
```

This specifies the path as `"/"`, which is passed as `$path`, so in your `function` the link path will be

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $path;
```

which will just put a / at the end of the root URL. You will need to pass the proper suffix at index instead of `"/"` when not on root.